# Coding games similar to Machinarium in Java?

Tags: 2d, java, adventure-games

I wan't to see how great of an idea is to start a game project like [Machinarium](http://machinarium.net/demo/) coded in Java. I'm not really good at Java yet, but it's the programming language I decided to go with first. Not really to learn a lot about games, but rather to have programming base if I ever decide to go with C++/C.

Comment: Do you have any other programming language experience?

Comment: I'm not planning on jumping right away to make a game like this. It's not a realistic goal, but I'm decided to learn JAVA. I would love to make something like Machinarium in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JAVA is a perfectly viable language for creating an adventure game like Machinarium. All the tools are there. However if you haven't created a game before it might be a good idea to first get a good feel on how games are structured (code wise). Maybe follow a tutorial on creating text-based adventure like this one http://www.javacoffeebreak.com/text-adventure/index.html first. And then later tack on the graphics. You can use OpenGL and what not for that :).

As always, small small steps at first :)

Comment: Yes! Thanks for the answer. I was afraid this community was dead. I'm messing around with libs like Slick2D and LWJGL. I know is practically impossible to jump to make games like that without a couple of years getting familiar and doing more basic stuff! But a game like Machinarium would me my ultimate goal :)

Comment: Don't worry, have some fun. Try a few basic games first. (Text based, then a platformer, then something slightly more interesting). And remember to keep having fun. Also Slick2D looks nice, should be fun to learn that after you finished a simple text adventure. :)

Comment: If you want to learn a lot about opengl, graphic cards etc. I would recommend you to use LIBGDX, as you can target windows, linux, mac and android very easily. When you want to make the game as easy as possible and don't care about the technical things, then stick to slick2d, as it abstracts the whole opengl stuff into a very accessible 2d rendering system... The performance is a bit worse than in libgdx, but it shouldn't have any impact on a game like machinarium.

Answer (score -1):

I'm going to give my opinions about Java and explain why it's not good for games in general:

1. it's performance hungry, especially for the memory ( RAM and CPU/memory controller ), this also means that to run a simple game you need at least a computer with medium range specs
2. the JVM it's not standardize, especially on Mac, the first official Java version on Mac is the actual version ( Java 7, first and only one ), the previous versions are provided by Apple and are not standard, especially for the part related to the window system and the graphical appearance, also in many GNU/Linux installations the default JVM is OpenJDK and not Java from Oracle
3. Java generates bytecode and not compiled code, even if you obfuscates the code it's really really easy to crack, sometimes it's also easy to do reverse engineer
4. If you distribute java code you are implicitly asking the user for installing the JVM, most of the users do not have this abilities and most of the times they just expect that your program will run/install right after the download without additional software
5. for what i know [Machinarium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machinarium) is in Flash ( probably even worst than Java ), the original one on PC/MAC/Linux, the others are porting.
6. if you are interested in Java and you want to code games, do yourself a favor and just use C#

Comment: Well I'm aiming to learn code that's why I choose JAVA as a first... I'm sure if I get the hang of it and start improving I would jump to C/C++. You are right JAVA might not be a smart choice for someone that really wan't to make a good comercial game, but I just wanted to know if something similar could be done to learn from. I'm not seeking to create a masterpiece from JAVA.

Comment: @RufioLJ yes, but even if your expectation are low, just use C/C++ with a bunch of pre-packed library instead of using Java which is a language that will worth nothing in the future, i don't know your projects but learning Java for this entire world can be useless, so my last point is about C# that is a language really really similar to Java but at least it is used in gaming world.

Comment: I don't completely agree with this answer. A agree to 1 and 2 though. If you use java with an opengl wrapper (lwjgl, jogl etc.), that graphics heavy parts are calculated by the graphics card and not by the processor. For simple games (I count machinarium as simple game) it is sufficient and provides the advantage, that it is much easier than c/c++. For something graphics heavy, as machinarium, flash is also a viable solution (basically, flash was made for such things). One last word, I find it a bit hypocrit to taunt java and then suggest c# in the same breath, as it has the same implications.

Comment: @tomvangreen yes, but a CV with C# in it is really different from a CV with Java for the gaming world; even if they are similar or identical the industry treat them in a very different way.

Comment: Besides that, that c# also runs in a vm, there isn't even an official version on any system other than windows. Yes, there is mono, but mono is not feature complete against the original .net. Also, libraries like libgdx can export games, that can be run on linux, windows, mac, android etc. Btw, just want to state that I work as a programmer and C# / .NET is my main development environment, so this is not a bash against C#. I just want to say, if the OP wants to use java, it is his decision and should be respected...

Comment: Oh and another thing. You don't have to let the user install a jvm. You can embeded a jvm in your games assets. There are even some special jvms optimized for gaming, that can be distributed with the game, and the user does not have to install any JRE/JDK or whatever.

Comment: @tomvangreen i know C# and I still think that even if it offers the same boundaries that Java does, you better learn C# instead of Java. Embedding a JVM is not an easy task from the license viewpoint and also this new JVM are most likely small projects with not so much years of testing and know-how. I still think that learning C/C++ is probably even easier than learning Java and is undoubtedly better for both the performance and the future.

Comment: I know both and Java is as easy to learn as C#, but it offers platform independence (that is btw. the reason, why I chose java over c# for my projects). If you use a framwork like slick2d or lwjgl, you can do very nice games pretty quick. I agree, if you want to make a AAA+ 3d high end graphics game, both c# and java are the wrong way to go, but I think in that case you would stick to an engine like UDK or CryEngine. It really depends on your goal. and sorry about my first comment. It sounds somewhat harsh. Shouldn't have that tone.

Comment: Seriously? C# run in a VM just like java but guess what, it's not portable... to me your post makes no sense since great games are made in java, even commercial ones (i will take Minecraft as example once again).

Comment: @nathan and Minecraft fits my list perfectly, you can find cracked versions that you can't distinguish from the original one and a game like Minecraft is also performance hungry and offers horrible performances. Also it's written in a really bad way because it's not even portable even if it's written in Java. You are making an example about a successfull game written in Java, you haven't prove that Java is good for games. C# it's not like Java when comes to the JVM because C# make a difference between the CLR and the CLI, you can code a game in XNA without having the Java crappy performance.

Comment: Not to start this entire language discussion again. But C# is arguably faster (or at least just as fast) as Java and C#/.NET is an open specification and portable (MONO does a great job and MONOGAME even wraps up most of XNA, C#'s most prominent game development tool. C#/XNA games can  run on Android, iPhone, Windows Phone, the Xbox 360, Linux, and the PC :). So C# vs Java is just taste if you ask me (and they are so much alike in syntax that you can switch anytime).

Comment: I do not want to fall into a debate around languages, it's not the right place for it heh. I'll only add that a ton of games get cracked... every games? even those written in other languages than Java. So it's not (to me) a viable argument. Minecraft offer poor performance (maybe even if i manage to run it with decent cpu usage by setting it properly) but who cares? How many people play Minecraft? You want to make a game and you like Java (because it's an awesome language) then do your game with Java.